# Xamarin Realm in shared project, error "Fody not properly installed"

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, realm, fody

I’m trying to add Realm to Xamarin project.

Project contain two platform-specific projects (Android and iOS) and PCL (.NET framework).

I can successfully add realm separately to each platform, but when I’m trying to move my code to PCL, I have an error “Fody not properly installed. PCLNamespace.MyRealmObject is a RealmObject but has not been woven.”.

I added NuGet Realm package to each project and PCL.

I tried Realm documentation FAQ [“Failing to Weave”](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#failing-to-weave)
and most of solutions from similar issue ["Xamarin android Crash"](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/541)

Non of that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found what was blocking PCL to use realm. I’m posting an answer for those who would come across similar issue.

When I created new PCL I could add and use Realm without any errors. Making a diff of both PCLs give me an answer; faulty PCL had `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` packages, and when I delated it from project packages (via Xamarin Studio) that fix an issue.

Although I fix my issue, I’m not understanding how packages could block functionality of the other, so if somebody know an answer for that I would appreciate a comment:)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your shared project a *Shared Project* or a PCL?

If it is a PCL, you also need to add the Realm NuGet to the PCL.

Comment: sorry for slow reply. What I meant is PCL not share project (I edited my question), however I already had Realm NuGet added in it. Finally I resolved this issue and answered my questions if you would be interested. Thanks